# Area calculator with three fields in jQuery (calculate based on missing value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, area

I'm working on an calculator that has three fields: "length," "width," "area." "Area" is equal to "length" x "width". However, my client needs to ability to update any two of these fields to get the third -- what I currently have only calculates area when length or width changes and doesn't have the ability to calculate the missing value.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {
  $('input').change(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parents("td").children("div").children("div"),
        length = $parent.find('input[id*="field-length-0-value"]').val(),
        width = $parent.find('input[id*="field-width-0-value"]').val();
        $parent.find('input[id*="field-area-0-value"]').val(length * width); 
  });
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786716/auto-updating-width-length-area-using-jquery-and-drupal6), [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/olone5/edit)

**How do I make the length or width update when the area is modified?**

Many thanks!

Comment: This is too ambiguous. When the area changes, length can change, width can change, or both. Do you want length and width to both change by the same proportion?

Comment: I should have been clearer, apologies. The user will always have 2 of 3 values -- either length and area, or width and area, or length and width. If length or width are changed, area should recalculate -- this already occurs. If area has a value and either length or width does not, whichever value is missing should be calculated from the area divided by the existing value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huzzah! I figured it out. Reproducing code below for somebody in a similar situation:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {   
  $('input').change(function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id'),
    $parent = $(this).parents("td").children("div").children("div"),
    lengthId = $parent.find('input[id*="field-length-0-value"]'),
    length = lengthId.val(),
    lengthAtt = lengthId.attr('id'),
    widthId = $parent.find('input[id*="field-width-0-value"]'),
    width = widthId.val(),       
    widthAtt = widthId.attr('id'),
    areaId = $parent.find('input[id*="field-area-0-value"]'),
    area = areaId.val(),
    areaAtt = areaId.attr('id');


        if ((currentId == lengthAtt) && (area == 0)){
        areaId.val(length * area); //Area when l * w
        }
        if ((currentId == lengthAtt) && (width == 0)){
        widthId.val(area / length); //width when a / l
        }
        if ((currentId == widthAtt) && (area == 0)){
        areaId.val(width * length); //area when w * l
        }
        if ((currentId == widthAtt) && (length == 0)){
        lengthId.val(area / width); //length when a / w
        }
        if ((currentId == areaAtt) && (width == 0)){
        widthId.val(area / length);//width when a / l
        }
        if ((currentId = areaAtt) && (length == 0)){
        lengthId.val(area / width); //length when a / w 
        }
  });
});
```

I'm sure there's a few places where it can be optimized...

Answer (score 1):

Give each input a unique id then:

```
$('input').change(function() {

var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
if (currentId == 'area'){
//DO AREA CALCULATIONS
}
if (currentId == 'length'){
//DO LENGTH CALCULATIONS
}
if (currentId == 'width'){
//DO WIDTH CALCULATIONS
}

});
```

Comment: Each has a unique ID, but I don't know what it is beforehand -- please look at the "Source" link in the above post, this code interacts with a Drupal CCK component that allows repeatable form elements.

Comment: That's quite messy and I'm not quite sure what you do? As long as the order doesn't change you could make an array of all inputs, number them and then determine what each box was from that. Obviously having ids would be better but I'm unfamiliar with CCK.

Comment: The HTML part is really daunting, I know. In short, there's a series of rooms, each with three rows: height, width, area (there are other fields for units, but ignore these for now). Users can add another row by clicking a button. The IDs for the three inputs mentioned above are like: edit-field-room-0-value-field-length-0-value, edit-field-room-0-value-field-width-0-value, and edit-field-room-0-value-field-area-0-value; when a new row is added, it becomes edit-field-room-1-value-field-length-0-value, edit-field-room-1-value-field-width-0-value and edit-field-room-1-value-field-area-0-value.

Comment: I had the feeling I needed a bunch of conditionals, so giving +10 for the help. Thanks!